# debuild can't find rustc

Tags: debian, packaging, rust

I am trying to package my Rust application for Debian but I encounter some issues. I try to build with

```
debuild -us -uc
```

but it gives the error

```
Running "rustc --version" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rustc': 'rustc'"
```

From the command `cd debian/build && meson --prefix=/usr ../..`
But when try to run it manually it doesn't give any errors. Why can't it see `rustc`?

Comment: Where is your `rustc`?

Comment: It is in `/home/<HOME-NAME>/.cargo/bin/rustc`

Answer (score 1):

`debuild` intentionally sanitizes the environment for security reasons, according to the manual page:

> As environment variables can affect the building of a package, often unintentionally, debuild sanitises the environment by removing all environment variables except for `TERM`, `HOME`, `LOGNAME`, `GNUPGHOME`, `PGPPATH`, `GPG_AGENT_INFO`, `GPG_TTY`, `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`, `FAKEROOTKEY`, `DEBEMAIL`, `DEB_*`, the (`C`, `CPP`, `CXX`, `LD` and `F`)`FLAGS` variables and their `_APPEND` counterparts and the locale variables `LANG` and `LC_*`. `TERM` is set to `dumb` if it is unset, and `PATH` is set to `/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11`.

In general, you should not build a Debian package using software that is not also a Debian package because it's impossible to produce a reproducible build and for others to build the package outside of your environment.  Therefore, the best solution is to use the Debian `rustc` package, use a newer version from Debian unstable, or build a newer `rustc` if you require one.  If you are sure that you really want to do this anyway and thoroughly understand the consequences, there are configuration options to adjust the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: That makes sense. But if I want to only publish the binary package, I don't see any reason for this.

Comment: TBH, if you don’t care about build dependencies, and you want to use compilers which aren’t packaged, it sounds like you’d be better off using `dpkg-deb -b` rather than trying to start with a source package.